# How to add Java EE plugin in plain eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded a plain eclipse which does not have java ee prospective. Now I want to add Java EE in ecipse. How can I do it?

I want add tomcat as a server in eclipse.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just install those plugins you need via the project update site:

```
Help > Install New Software...
```

In the `Work with:` drop-down select your release (in my case Indigo 3.7.1), wait a few seconds and eclipse shows you all plugins available under the project's umbrella. Then select the plugins you need:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be using Spring, you can download the Springsource Tool Suite from [here](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts).