# Create EJB project capability not available in eclipse JUNO Version: 4.2.2

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb, eclipse-juno

In my Eclipse Juno Version: 4.2.2, I try to create new EJB project but it is not available in new project creation window.

`File > New > Other` ....

Is there a plugin I need to use for this? but in every EJB tutorial it says directly. 
" Select File -> New -> Other. Select EJB -> J2EE EJB Module and click Next. "

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ejb.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftecrtpro.html

Comment: You must download the Java EE release and not the basic one (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ > Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers). Btw: the tutorial you refer to is fairly outdated (EJB 2.1) - you should look at EJB 3.x

Comment: I can not use other versions as it conflict with Maven plugin. So I have to use this Eclipse version. Don't I have any other option like use a plugin ?

Comment: You can download the additional plugins using `Help > install new Software` from the eclipse file menu. 2 years ago I wrote an answer for Indigo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046661/how-to-add-java-ee-plugin-in-plain-eclipse/8046730#8046730 should still work similar

Comment: Well thanks for the info. I have the market place but which plugin to download? Do you know the name of the plugin?

Comment: No, I do not have the names available. Just choose those that make sense (look at the categories, e.g. Java EE) - and dependency managements works well.